# Read BAM with tags to tbl / recursive dplyr::bind_cols for list of lists

Tags: r, dplyr, bioinformatics, bioconductor, purrr

I would like to read in a BAM file including some tags, then convert this to a `tibble` for further processing.

Generally, this can be achieved pretty simply:

```
library(Rsamtools)
library(tidyverse)
map.info <- c("rname", "strand", "pos")
map.params <- ScanBamParam(what = map.info)
bam <- scanBam(bam.file, param = map.params)
```

`scanBam` returns a list with named vectors `rname`, `strand` and `pos`, which can be easily joined using `dplyr::bind_cols(bam)`. However, say I am interested in the `MD`-tag, I need to do the following:

```
map.params <- ScanBamParam(what = map.info, tag = c("MD"))
bam <- scanBam(bam.file, param = map.params)
```

Now, `bam` is a list of lists, with named vectors `rname`, `strand` and `pos` as preivously, but also another `tag` which is itself a list, with one named vector `MD`.

`dplyr::bind_cols` can not handle this nested list of lists, and throws an error, but `as.data.frame(bam)` works.

## TL;DR

A toy example boiling down to the question at heart:

```
> df.list <- list(a = 1:2, b = 3:4, c = 5:6)
> df.nest <- list(a = 1:2, b = 3:4, c = 5:6, d = list( e = 7:8 ))
> dplyr::bind_cols(df.list)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
       a     b     c
   <int> <int> <int>
 1     1     3     5
 2     2     4     6
> dplyr::bind_cols(df.nest)
Error in cbind_all(x) : Argument 4 must be length 2, not 1
> as.data.frame(df.nest)
  a b c e
1 1 3 5 7
2 2 4 6 8
```

Is there a way to recursively `bind_cols` in a nested list?

## Tentative answer

Inspired by @mt1022's answer, and without further inspection of `Rsamtools` base code, it seems that despite being formatted very similarly to the toy example, `scanBam` output does not behave like the toy example.

However, as we know what we're putting in, the following should also achieve a full merged `tibble`:

```
map.info <- c("rname", "strand", "pos")
map.params <- ScanBamParam(what = map.info, tag = c("MD", "NM"))
bam <- scanBam(bam.file, param = map.params)
bam.tbl <- bind_cols(do.call(bind_cols, bam[[1]][c("rname", "strand", "pos")]),
                     do.call(bind_cols, bam[[1]]$tag))
```

It seems more hacky than what I had hoped for (or expected), but it works.

## Benchmarking

There are three options, that lead to a similar result:

1. `as.data.frame(bam)`
2. `bind_cols(do.call(bind_cols, bam[[1]][map.info]), do.call(bind_cols, bam[[1]]$tag))`
3. `bind_cols(lapply(bam, as.data.frame), .id = 'rn')`

I thought an example bam file, with `10762160` lines should give a good idea on what approach works fastest.

```
> length(bam[[1]]$rname)
[1] 10762160
> system.time(for (i in 1:100) as.data.frame(bam))
   user  system elapsed
 70.565  25.821  96.699
> system.time(for (i in 1:100) bind_cols(do.call(bind_cols, bam[[1]][mapI]), do.call(bind_cols, bam[[1]]$tag)))
   user  system elapsed
  0.124   0.020   0.144
> system.time(for (i in 1:100) dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(bam, as.data.frame), .id = 'rn'))
   user  system elapsed
108.091  36.046 144.623
```

As 'clunky' as it seems, I guess the nested calls to `bind_col` is quickest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by this example in manual of `bind_cols`:

```
# You can mix vectors and data frames:
bind_rows(
  c(a = 1, b = 2),
  data_frame(a = 3:4, b = 5:6),
  c(a = 7, b = 8)
)
```

I think we can try:

```
do.call(bind_cols, df.nest)
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#       a     b     c     e
#   <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1     3     5     7
# 2     2     4     6     8
```

#### edit: a real example

```
library(Rsamtools)
# generate sample data using internal bam file of Rsamtools
which <- RangesList(seq1=IRanges(1000, 2000),
                    seq2=IRanges(c(100, 1000), c(1000, 2000)))
what <- c("rname", "strand", "pos")
param <- ScanBamParam(which=which, what=what, tag = c("NM"))

bamFile <- system.file("extdata", "ex1.bam", package="Rsamtools")
bam <- scanBam(bamFile, param=param)

# convert bam to a data.frame
bam.df <- dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(bam, as.data.frame), .id = 'rn')

#                  rn rname strand  pos NM
# 1    seq1:1000-2000  seq1      +  970  0
# 2    seq1:1000-2000  seq1      +  971  0
# 3    seq1:1000-2000  seq1      +  972  0
# ......
```

Comment: Works nicely with the toy example, but for some strange reason not with the real-world bioinformatic one.
Rechecked the data type of `bam` above, and it's actually: `list(list(a = 1:2, b = 3:4, c = 5:6, d = list(e = c('a', 'b'), f = c('d', 'e'))))`, but this, too, works with `do.call`, but not the bioinformatic one... I'm a bit stumped.

Comment: Probably because your toy example has the same number of rows in the nested list `d` as the rest of the columns. Try it with `d has 4 rows`, and I'm guessing your toy example breaks.

Comment: BAM files are very structured, and difficult to store in `NxM` format. I would try to work with it in list format. If you insist on converting to table format, what I would recommend is storing the nested list `d` as a single character. Try `unlist()` and save the result as a single column.

Comment: Good point, but actually not the case. The only remaining difference is that `a` and `b` are `factors`. In the real world example `a`, `b`, `c`, `e` and `f` all have `length = 191199` and `d` has `length = 2`.

Comment: That's strange. Another possible reason is that bioconductor rewrite too many base R functions which may cause errors silently. Do you have specific reason to process bam files with R. I would suggest `samtools` or `pysam`.

Comment: No strong reason in particular. I used a mix of `pysam`, `pandas` and `awk` before to do some tabulation and evaluation of the mapped reads, and in an effort of streamlining and recent increase in `R` usage, thought I'd see if I can stick to one set of tools and optimise old ones at the same time. FWIW, the following works: `bind_cols(do.call(bind_cols, bam[[1]][c('rname', 'strand', 'pos')]), do.call(bind_cols, bam[[1]]$tag))`